# Prove that $\Bbb F_2(\sqrt[3] x)$ is separable over $\Bbb F_2(x)$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Prove that $\Bbb F_2(\sqrt[3] x)$ is separable over $\Bbb F_2(x)$.

Now I was trying taking $X^3 -x\in \Bbb F_2( x)[X] $ then if I show this polynomial is separable then I am done. Now $X^3 -x=(X-x^{1/3})(X^2 +aX +b) \Rightarrow b=x^{2/3}, a=x^{1/3}$.

So considering $X^2+x^{1/3}X+x^{2/3}$ we can't factorize using Shreedhar Acharya's rule as $char (F)=2$. So taking $X^2+x^{1/3}X+x^{2/3}=(X-c)(X-d)$ where $c,d \in \Bbb F_2(\sqrt[3] x)$ what will be the solution of $c,d$?

Comment: To show separability, it's enough to show that the polynomial and its derivative have no common roots.

Comment: The other zeros are $\alpha x^{1/3}$ and $\alpha^2 x^{1/3}$, where $\alpha$ is a primitive cubic root of unity. That root $\alpha\in\Bbb{F}_4$ meaning that those other roots are in the extension field $\Bbb{F}_4(x^{1/3})=\Bbb{F}_2(x^{1/3},\alpha)$. Compare this with the possibly more familiar question of showing that $x^3-2$ is separable over $\Bbb{Q}$. If you adjoin a single root, say $\root3\of2$, to $\Bbb{Q}$ you don't get the other two roots in the field $K=\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)$ because those are complex whereas the elements of $K$ are all real.